# Choosing a parameter type based on template parameter

Tags: templates, c++11, types

I am writing a C++11 template function `void foo(T, U)` taking two parameters:

The first parameter which can either be of type A1 or of type B1.
If the first parameter is of type A1, the second parameter is of type A2;
If the first parameter is of type B1, the second parameter is of type B2;

Since the second parameter depends on the first one, is there a way of writing this function needing only one template parameter?

Something along the line of

```
template class <T>
void foo(T t, std::conditional<A1* tmp = dynamic_cast<T*>(&t), A2, B2>::type);
```

might work, but its ugly and needs RTTI.

Is there a good way of achieving this?

Comment: Unless A and B are each one a template o the other one you just need 2 specializations, make general implementation private and accessible only through public specializations, other wise you have to model a `TypeSpecialization` just as ROX did.

Comment: @DarioOO  Thansk DarioOO, but this results in code duplication...

Comment: Since you have a relation between types, you can hide partially duplication using ROX answer (if you have more than 2 methods with same parameters you save duplication), in case there's no relation or multiple relations within types is probably better just doing specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done without RTTI. how best to do it depends on how A1 and A2 are related.

If you control the classes you can add a using or typedef into A1

```
class A1
{
     using RelatedType = A2;
}
```

and similar for B1 and B2

then

```
template class <T>
void foo(T t, T::RelatedType t2);
```

If you cant edit A1 you can create a type trait

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeRelation  // would have a better name if we knew why they were related
{
      // can put a default related type here if you want
}
```

and then use template specialization (example for As, but need similar for Bs)

```
template<>
struct TypeRelation<A1>
{
     using RelatedType = A2;
}
```

and then the declaration becomes

```
template class <T>
void foo(T t, typename TypeRelation<T>::RelatedType t2);
```

C++11s decltype may also be suitable depending on how the classes are related.

Comment: Did you mean `typename TypeRelation<T>::RelatedType`?